# Poker game with dice

Tags: probability

You play poker by rolling 5 ordinary die.  Numbers on the die correspond to ranks on the cards. For example, two pairs means you rolled the numbers $aabbc$ in any order, where $a,b,c$ are different numbers. Calculate:

a) P(full house), ie the pattern $aabbb$

Attempt: By counting, we have $6.1.5.1.1. \frac{5!}{2! 3!}$ possible rearrangements. Dividing this by the sample space, $|s| = 6^5$ gives approx $0.04,$ I believe this is the right answer

b) P(one pair), ie the pattern $aabcd$

Attempt: So there are $6.1.5.4.3\frac{5!}{2!}$ possible rearrangements. Divide by $|s|$ to get a number > 1. I am not sure where I went wrong here. My reasoning for the $5!/2!$ was that for any one combination of 5 numbers, you can order them  5! ways. However, 2 of the numbers are the same, so we divide by 2!.

c) P({$aabbc$}) = $6.1.5.1.4.\frac{5!}{2!.2!}$ all divided by $6^5$ gives 0.46, exactly twice the suggested answer.

I also wonder now why the sample space would not be $(6^5 . 5!)$?

d) How many rolls you need for a full house on average?
Attempt: So to get a full house, you need $aabbb$. Roll a die. Roll a die again.The expected number of rolls needed to get a matching number on the first roll is 6. I tried to extend this arguement to find how many rolls you need to roll a different number other than the one already got, but didn't get very far. I suppose this method also neglects the fact that we don't care about the order of the full house. Could I have a hint on this one (not the answer)?

Comment: [Poker dice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_dice) has some probabilities

Comment: For the dots as multiplication, use `\cdot` as in $6\cdot5\cdot4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**One pair:** There are $6$ ways to choose what we will have two of. For each such way, there are $\dbinom{5}{2}$ ways to decide *where* the numbers shall be in the list.

For every way of getting this far, there are $\dbinom{5}{3}$ ways to decide on the *collection* of singletons, and then $3!$ ways to list them. Multiply.

Or else more easily, once we have dealt with the pair, there are $(5)(4)(3)$ ways to fill the gaps.

**Two pairs:** This one is tricky, it is quite common to get an answer twice as big as the truth. The two **kinds** that we will have pairs of can be chosen in $\dbinom{6}{2}$ ways. For every such choice, the lonely number can be chosen in $4$ ways.

Now the cards of the **higher** chosen kind can be placed in $\dbinom{5}{2}$ ways, and for each such choice, the lonely number can be placed in $3$ ways.

(Instead you **may** have reasoned like this: The **first** kind we have a pair in can be chosen in $6$ ways, and then the second kind we have a pair in can be chosen in $5$ ways. However, there is no "first kind" or second kind, so if we use that sort of reasoning we need to then divide by $2$.)

**Waiting time:** Let the probability of a full house be $p$. This was calculated by you earlier. Now it is a standard fact that for a geometric distribution where the probability of success is $p$, the mean waiting time if $\dfrac{1}{p}$.

There are various ways to show this. One is to sum  the infinite series 
$$p+2(1-p)p+3(1-p)^2p+4(1-p)^3p+\cdots.$$
Another is to let the mean waiting time be $w$. On the first toss, we either have success (probability $p$) or failure.  We used up one toss. If success, it's over, need no more tosses. If failure, on average we need w.  Thus
$$w=1+(1-p)w.$$
Solve for $w$.

Comment: Where exactly did I go wrong with my answers for b) and c)?  I used the same reasoning for these questions as I did in a) and in a), I got the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Also, how is it clear that we have a geometric distribution?

Comment: By the *definition* of geometric distribution. Suppose we have probability $p\ne 0$ of "success" on any trial, and repeat experiment until we get the first success. Let $X$ be the number of trials. Then $X$ has geometric distribution.

Comment: So you are defining the probability of success $p$ as getting 5 rolls which give a full house and failure if the 5 rolls are not a full house. Then each trial is rolling the five die? I know the meaning of geometric distribution, i'am just trying to apply it here. Can you tell me where I went wrong in part b and c? Thanks .

Comment: For (b) the problem is the $5.\cdot 4\cdot 3$. Maybe you thought thusly: Pick a number other than the one we have $2$ of ($5$ choices). **Then** pick another number ($4$ choices), **then** another ($3$ choices). But for example picking $6$, then $1$, then $2$ is the same as picking $2$ then $6$ then $1$. So you are overcounting by a factor of $3!$. The issue with two pairs is similar, a pair of $2$'s and a pair of $6$'s is same as pair of $6$'s, pair of $2$'s. There was no problem with full house, since three $5$'s and two $4$'s is not same as three $4$'s and two $5$'s.